# zendesk app tools ZAT Installation errorFailed to build gem native extension

Tags: zendesk

I am trying to install "ZAT" the Zendesk app tools following [the documentation](https://developer.zendesk.com/documentation/apps/zendesk-app-tools-zat/installing-and-using-the-zendesk-apps-tools/#installing-zat), but receiving this error: \

> Building native extensions. This could take a while...
> ERROR:  Error installing zendesk_apps_tools:
> ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

> current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/ext

> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -I /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20220105-47488-6pwgmm.rb extconf.rb
> checking for -lcrypto... *** extconf.rb failed ***
> Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
> libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
> need configuration options.

ruby version => ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) 
xcode-select => xcode-select version 2384.
macOs : BIg Sur version 11.6.2

any idea what is the issue?

Comment: Have you checked if you have correct access rights to the installation folder. 
Try installing rvm first, install the ruby using that and then follow the document. 

Also installation using `brew` also helps

Comment: @Karun, Thank you, rvm solved the issue.

Comment: I ll put that in answer, glad to help ou out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installation via `rvm` resolves this issue.

Comment: If anyone lands here, instead of `zat` you can now use `zcli` instead which is node based.

Docs here: https://developer.zendesk.com/documentation/apps/app-developer-guide/zcli/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my `Mac Big Sur 11.6 with M1 chip`. None of the suggested solutions helps me (I tried to reinstall Xcode, updating/reinstalling command line tools, deal with the installation of thin separately, etc.). One thing that really helps me it's changing the `ruby version to 2.6.9` with rbenv (https://gorails.com/setup/osx/11-big-sur - check Installing Ruby . Follow this instruction, but choose another ruby version). After change ruby version, make sure the correct version of ruby is currently selected with `ruby -v` and then try execute `gem install zendesk_apps_tools` again. I tried several versions of ruby before it worked for me, but in the end everything was fine on 2.6.9 version